# WebDriver: Use Firefox Developer Tools in Selenium test case

Tags: http, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, automated-tests, firefox-developer-tools

I wonder if it is possible to use functionality of Firefox Developer Tools from within a Selenium/WebDriver test case. Specifically, I want to export HTTP requests sent by a web site as HAR file.

I am aware of using a Firefox extension and adding it to a profile like this (in Java):

```
FirefoxProfile.addExtension(java.io.File extensionToInstall)
FirefoxProfile.setPreference(java.lang.String key,
                 java.lang.String value)
```

But for this I would need DevTools as XPI file and I couldn't find any info on that.

I am also aware of setting desired capabilities like this (in Java):

```
FirefoxDriver(Capabilities desiredCapabilities) 
Capabilities.setCapability(java.lang.String capabilityName, java.lang.String value)
```

But I don't know which capabilities to set in order to use the HAR file export functionality.

I have read a lot of comments and answers to similar questions which boiled down to:

- Use another testing tool (Sikuli)
- Use another browser (Chrome)
- Use another addon (Firebug+Netexport, nice [example](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/))

Anyway, I would like to know a way to do that using Firefox Developer Tools.

Comment: You could execute test and keep wire shark open set to record all browser activity and You could tell shark to take specific call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses Firefox's native devtools and an addon called [HAR Export Trigger](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-export-trigger/). Although a beta, it works with:

- Firefox: '43.0.4'
- Selenium: '2.48.2'
- os.name: 'Linux'
- os.version: '3.13.0-74-generic'
- java.version: '1.7.0_91'

This is a simple example code:

```
/**Test class for exporting HTTP requests of a web page to HAR files.*/
public class HarExportTest  {
    /**Absolute path needed because FF profile for Selenium is temporary.*/
    private final static String HARDIR = "/home/test/HAR_Demo/target";

    public static void main(String[] args) {   
        WebDriver driver = null;

        try {
            // Init
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(buildNetmonitorProfile());
            final File harDir = new File(HARDIR);
            final int numFiles = harDir.listFiles().length;
            System.out.println(harDir.getPath() + ": " + numFiles);         
            // Load test page
            driver.get("https://ixquick.com");
            // Wait for new file
            for (int c=0; c<180; c++) {
                if (harDir.listFiles().length > numFiles) {
                    System.out.println("added");
                    break;
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }
            System.out.println(harDir.getPath() + ": " + harDir.listFiles().length);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            System.err.println(exc);
        }

        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    private static FirefoxProfile buildNetmonitorProfile() throws IOException {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();  

        // Load extensions         
        File harExport = new File("harexporttrigger-0.5.0-beta.7.xpi"); //adjust path as needed
        profile.addExtension(harExport);

        // Enable the automation without having a new HAR file created for every loaded page.
        profile.setPreference("extensions.netmonitor.har.enableAutomation", true);
        // Set to a token that is consequently passed into all HAR API calls to verify the user.
        profile.setPreference("extensions.netmonitor.har.contentAPIToken", "test");
        // Set if you want to have the HAR object available without the developer toolbox being open.
        profile.setPreference("extensions.netmonitor.har.autoConnect", true);

        // Enable netmonitor
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.enabled", true);
        // If set to true the final HAR file is zipped. This might represents great disk-space optimization especially if HTTP response bodies are included.
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.compress", false);
        // Default name of the target HAR file. The default file name supports formatters
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.defaultFileName", "Autoexport_%y%m%d_%H%M%S");
        // Default log directory for generate HAR files. If empty all automatically generated HAR files are stored in <FF-profile>/har/logs
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.defaultLogDir", HARDIR);
        // If true, a new HAR file is created for every loaded page automatically.
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.enableAutoExportToFile", true);
        // The result HAR file is created even if there are no HTTP requests.
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.forceExport", true);   
        // If set to true, HTTP response bodies are also included in the HAR file (can produce significantly bigger amount of data).
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.includeResponseBodies", false);
        // If set to true the export format is HARP (support for JSONP syntax that is easily transferable cross domains)
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.jsonp", false);
        // Default name of JSONP callback (used for HARP format)
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.jsonpCallback", false);
        // Amount of time [ms] the auto-exporter should wait after the last finished request before exporting the HAR file.
        profile.setPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.pageLoadedTimeout", "2500");

        return profile;
    }
}
```

Output is:

> /home/test/HAR_Demo/target: 9
>   added
>   /home/test/HAR_Demo/target: 10